# Analog of MATLAB's conv2 in Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction, matlab, convolution

I have a matlab code

```
filter = 1;
F = conv2(double([1 2 1]),double([1 2 1]'))/16;
for i=1:some_integer
    filter = conv2(double(filter),double(F));
end
```

In the code `F = conv2(double([1 2 1]),double([1 2 1]'))/16;` equals
a 3 x 3 matrix `{{0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625}, {0.125, 0.25, 0.125}, {0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625}}`

`filter` changes the value in the first iteration from `1` to `F` and then in successive iteration the result (convolution matrix) gets larger and larger.

I am having trouble doing this convolution in Mathematica despite having looked at the documentation. Any idea how one might do such a convolution?

My attempt below to compute `F` before the loop looks incorrect somehow.

```
F = Flatten[(ListConvolve[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
            {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {-1, 1}, g, Plus, List]/16.0 ), 2]
```

because the same formulation for `ListConvolve` as shown above does not work for `filter` inside the loop.

Comment: How is `conv2` defined in MATLAB?

Comment: @MichaelE2 here is the link: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html

Comment: The calculation of `F` (testing using octave) appears to be identical to `Transpose[Outer[Times, {1,2,1}, {1,2,1}]]` (the `Transpose` is there for generality, but the result is symmetric in this case). Assuming `filter` is not a higher-order tensor by the end, however, `Outer` is not the same thing as `conv2`.

Comment: @eyorble agreed. but ListConvolve should be able to handle this case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if I've guessed definition of `conv2` accurately, but the following does reproduce the output of MATLAB. (Tested in Octave. )

```
conv2[A_?NumericQ, B_] := conv2[{{A}}, B]
conv2[A_?VectorQ, B_] := conv2[{A}, B]
conv2[A_, B_] := ListConvolve[A, B, {1, -1}, 0]

filter = 1;
F = conv2[{1, 2, 1}, List /@ {1, 2, 1}]/16.;
Nest[conv2[#, F] &, filter, 3]
```

[image]

For comparision, here is the output of Octave:

[image]

Comment: thanks. upvoted. i will accept the answer in a couple of days !

Comment: @AliHashmi Feel free to wait for better answer(s) :) .